# Spring @Qualifier not working when inheriting an interface

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have the following class structure:

```
class A{
...
}

class B{
...
}

interface I<T>{
...
 } 

@Component("childA")
class ChildA implements I<A>{
. ..
}

@Component("childB")
class ChildB implements I<B>{
...
}


class Test {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("childA")
public I<A> childOfA;
}
```

I get the exception no unique bean of type I for the property `childOfA`even after I use qualifier.

I have tried using `default-autowire = no` - it messed up with other parts of code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`Component` docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html), the value is only a "suggested name", not a specific qualifier. If you haven't yet, try changing it to explicitly specify the `Qualifier`, like so:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("childA")
class ChildA implements I<A>{ ... }

@Component
@Qualifier("childB")
class ChildB implements I<B>{ ... }
```

Comment: Even tried declaring the beans of childA and childB using the xml but still faced the same issue

Comment: I've seen in the past where Spring has some trouble figuring out template types due to Type Erasure. I'll try to remember how I solved it in the past and leave another comment -- eventually, though, I just got rid of the interfaces completely because they were wasteful in all of our use cases.